# flutter 'file not found' during build for ios

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to use the image_picker_web package,(https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker_web) and have put:

```
image_picker_web: ^1.0.9
```

in my pubspec.yaml file.

When I try building my project for iOS, I get the following error:

```
[ios/.symlinks/plugins/image_picker_web/example] flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in example...                         
Cannot open file, path = '/Users/username/.pub-cache/global_packages/image_picker_web_example/pubspec.lock' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
pub get failed (66; Cannot open file, path = '/Users/username/.pub-cache/global_packages/image_picker_web_example/pubspec.lock' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2))
exit code 66
```

With no other code in the project that uses that package, I get the same error. The only way to avoid it is to comment out image_picker_web: ^1.0.9 in my pubspec.yaml and run 'flutter pub get'

I created an issue in their git repo, under the assumption that it's a bug.  Is this the case? Are there any workarounds? (perhaps ignoring a package when building for a different platform?)

Comment: Does a `flutter clean` helps?

Comment: Apparently its trying to `get` on the `example` package, maybe its a bug on their part.

Comment: flutter clean does not help.  It might be a bug on their part.  Do you guys see the same thing if you register that package and try and build for ios?

Comment: Additionally, I ran flutter build ios and got:  -> Fetching podspec for `image_picker_web` from `.symlinks/plugins/image_picker_web/ios`
    [!] No podspec found for `image_picker_web` in `.symlinks/plugins/image_picker_web/ios`

Comment: I am sorry but I don't have a Mac OS to test it.

Comment: no worries.  thanks for trying to help.  it probably is a bug on their part.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, any fix?

Answer (score 3):

I ran the following command to fix a similar issue.

Remove all existing caches

`sudo rm -rf ~/.pub-cache`

Repair the cache

`flutter pub cache repair`

Reinstall the dependencies

`flutter packages get`